# Does the WebClient in Silverlight not support X509 Version 3?

Tags: ssl, silverlight, x509certificate

I have a device that generates a X509 Version 1 certificate for the IP of the device. The certificate is used in a REST API, running over HTTPS on the device.

My Silverlight 4 application uses the WebClient to communicate with the device over HTTPS - and it works fine.

I then changed the generation of the certificate to use the X509 Version 3 extension SubjectAltName – so that the certificate would work for multiple IP’s and domains.

It works fine to browse the REST API over HTTPS in a browser (no security warnings), but the Silverlight application can no longer communicate with the device over HTTPS – it just throws the "Security error" exception. I have tried using the IP and hostname in Silverlight but neither work.

Does the WebClient in Silverlight not support X509 Version 3?

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: What type of records do you use for the IP address in SAN? Correct would be iPaddress but MS has a long standing bug in certificate validation that it requires IP addresses to be specified as dNSname type. So you better use both types.

Comment: I had a support case with Microsoft and they responded that this behavior is by design (not a bug).

Comment: The record type was IP. I changed it to DNS – and now it works in Silverlight! However, if I now go over in Chrome or Firefox, I get a security warning :)

Comment: Sorry, using both types makes it work in Silverlight and browsing REST API in Chrome and Firefox. E.g. IP.1 = 192.168.1.10 and DNS.1 = 192.168.1.10.